# Why does FMX.TOpenDialog not work in Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am using a simple FMX TOpenDialog object in my app. Why does it not work in Android? nothing happens, it just skips right over the OpenDialog1.Execute and that's it.

Comment: Because it is not implemented on Android. Where would you like users to be able to select files from, e.g. from files deployed with your app, or external to your app?

Comment: `TOpenDialog` in FMX is just a wrapper for [`IFMXDialogService.DialogOpenFiles()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogService.DialogOpenFiles). Nothing stops Embarcadero (or users, for that matter) from implementing `DialogOpenFiles()` to display a custom dialog. Look at [`TPlatformServices.AddPlatformService()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.AddPlatformService). Android actually does have native open file dialogs, so I don't know why Embarcadero hasn't updated FMX to use them yet. But you certainly can, if needed.

Comment: @DaveNottage I need the user to open a local JSON file on the device, for now, just like the Windows and OSX versions of the app do. I don't understand why Embarcadero markets this product as a cross-platform development platform while leaving such gaping holes in the implementation, and worse yet, not documenting them properly in the help files.

Comment: Assuming that the JSON file they select is one of a collection deployed with your app, you could present a listbox with the names of the files. If the files are *not* deployed with your app, you could use a method similar to this demo: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/FilesSelector.

Comment: not sure if it's still not supported on Android, the docs don't seem to mention something indeed. Related articles/discussions: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/3773-browsing-for-certain-files-on-android/ - https://delphi-developers-archive.blogspot.com/2017/05/delphi-android-get-file-path-of-image.html - and of course the Kastri FileSelector mentioned above.